# Remove year and month in URL using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, seo, mod-rewrite

For example, to redirect old URLs of the form:

`/2016/10/mukunda-murari-kannada-songs-download.html`

To

`/mukunda-murari-kannada-songs-download.html`

I have already changed the permalink structure in WordPress, but wish to redirect the old URLs to the new, in the most efficient way, in order to help preserve SEO.

This is my code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Isn't this an option under permalinks? You shouldn't need to touch `HTAccess` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already changed the permalinks structure as @RickHellewell suggests, then you can do something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file (before the existing WP front-controller) to redirect the old URLs (with the stated format) in order to preserve SEO.

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/([a-z-]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, the regexp does't consider permalinks with digits. If you want to match permalinks with digits (like `/2016/10/mukunda-murari-kannada-songs-3-download.html`, note the **3**) you have to change to: `RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/([a-z-0-9]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your permalinks to "Post Name" in Settings, Permalinks?

Comment: You might want to "remove year and month in url using .htaccess" (ie. _redirect_) if you have already changed the permalinks in WP and the old URLs had already been indexed/linked to.

Comment: thank you. i changed in permalink as well as in htaccess now its working fine